# WPF Button backgrounds

Tags: c#, wpf, button

When the control is disabled the background behind the image becomes grey and when I mouse over it, the background behind my image also becomes highlighted.
How do I prevent that from happening?

XMAL

```
<Button x:Name="btnSubmitCase" Content="Button" Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="326" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="136,409,409,50" BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Hand" Click="btnSubmitCase_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Image Source="Resources/CaseButton.png"/>
                </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you'd put a `Button` *inside* the `ControlTemplate` for a `Button` instead of just using this XAML:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
    <Image Source="Resources/CaseButton.png" />>
</Button>
```

However, that *wasn't* your question, which there is a simple answer to... just don't put a `Button` into the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Button x:Name="btnSubmitCase" ...>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="Resources/CaseButton.png" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

The behaviour that you're describing is built in to the default `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` control. To remove it, just define your own `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

The default template for a button includes triggers that override the appearance when the button is hovered over, pressed, or disabled. (You can examine the Xaml for these if you edit the default theme in Blend.)

In order to prevent this behaviour, you need to override the template completely - what you've currently done is simply override your local button's template with another button that contains an image. One example of this would be a simple tweak of what you've already done:

```
<Button x:Name="btnSubmitCase" Content="Button" Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="326" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="136,409,409,50" BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Hand" Click="btnSubmitCase_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="Resources/CaseButton.png"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Note that this will remove all of the button's border and other state-change behaviour, and essentially just render a clickable image.